# Facebook Login through Node.js web application is returning 'Undefined' Fields in user profile as response after passport.js authentication

Tags: mysql, passport.js, facebook-login, passport-facebook

I am having a problem when I try to login through facebook in my project app it access the data in facebook account but return undefined fields. also I want to prompt the user again after successfull login by facebook to get informaton about his CNIC, MOBILE, ADDRESS, AGE, SEMESTER, DateOfAdmission that surely not available at facebook accounts of a user.
Here is my routes call, and passport function definition.

passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy({

```
    // pull in our app id and secret from our auth.js file
    clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL

},

// facebook will send back the token and profile
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
        console.log(profile.email) ;
        // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM student where email = ?", [profile.email], function(err, rows){
            if(rows.length){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Username/Email Already exist.'));
            }
            else{
                console.log("Profile: ", profile, "\n\n\n") ;

                    var newUserMysql = {
                        //id: "cs151071",
                        username: "cs123456",
                        password: bcrypt.hashSync("ab123456", null, null), // use the generateHash function in our user model
                        dateofadmission: "14/05/2016",
                        email: profile.email,
                        firstname: profile.firstname,
                        lastname: profile.lastname,
                        gender: profile.gender,
                        cnic: "12345-9876543-1",
                        address: "Malir",
                        mobile: "03312589633",
                        age: 23,
                        semester: 5
                    };

                    console.log(newUserMysql) ;

                    console.log("username: ", newUserMysql.username, "\n") ;
                    console.log("password: ", newUserMysql.password, "\n") ;
                    console.log("dateofadmission: ", newUserMysql.dateofadmission, "\n") ;
                    console.log("email: ", newUserMysql.email, "\n") ;
                    console.log("firstname: ", newUserMysql.firstname, "\n") ;
                    console.log("lastname: ", newUserMysql.lastname, "\n") ;
                    console.log("gender: ", newUserMysql.gender, "\n") ;
                    console.log("cnic: ", newUserMysql.cnic, "\n") ;
                    console.log("address: ", newUserMysql.address, "\n") ;
                    console.log("mobile: ", newUserMysql.mobile, "\n") ;
                    console.log("age: ", newUserMysql.age, "\n") ;
                    console.log("semester: ", newUserMysql.semester, "\n") ;

                    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO student (firstname, lastname, username, password, cnic, address, age, cellNumber, dateOfAdmission, gender, email, semester_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                    connection.query(insertQuery, [newUserMysql.firstname, newUserMysql.lastname, newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password, newUserMysql.cnic, newUserMysql.address, newUserMysql.age, newUserMysql.mobile, newUserMysql.dateOfAdmission, newUserMysql.gender, newUserMysql.email, newUserMysql.semester], function(err, rows) {
                        console.log(err) ;

                        //newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                        return done(null, newUserMysql);
                    });

            }
        })

    });

}));
```

Here is the routes call.

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'] }));
// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/signup',
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages    });
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this field in your Facebook strategy configuration,

```
profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email'],
```

Like,

```
new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
  profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
}), ...)
```

You can refer this: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook